# Fundamental difference between Susy 2.0 and SingularityGS

Tags: sass, susy-compass, singularitygs, susy-sass

I am wondering if there is any key differences between these two grid systems. I can't see any on the surface and dont know why I would want to choose one over the other. I built sites with both singularity and susy 1 in the last few months and they both worked great. They both appear to be actively developed and built by solid folks. Is there any specific advantages that one offers over the other? Are there any situations where on might be a better choice?

Answer (score 6):

Susy 1 and Singularity 1.1.2 offered different types of responsive grids. Now, however, Susy 2.1.1 and Singularity 1.2.0 are quite similar in that respect. I believe that Susy incorporated some ideas from Singularity. I have re-built my website using Susy 2.1.1; previously I had used Singularity 1.1.2. I have tried Singularity 1.2.0 but at the moment there are some changes in coding that I cannot get to work. IMHO, they are both excellent but there is one huge difference. The documentation for Susy 2.1.1 is very good, whereas Singularity's documentation is still minimal and the Changelogs don't help a lot. There is also a video at 'sass bites #29' which though long-winded gives quite a lot of help with Susy 2. I have found (again) that the documentation isn't perfect. For example the methodology for setting a background or overlay grid can vary and I have found (from the video) a neater way of doing that. The new $maps and the new functions are really helpful in Susy 2 (e.g. @include break). There are a lot of changes in functions in Susy and Singularity and Susy's comprehensive documentation is essential.